# zip' or 'tar' commands to generate the archive to standard output

Tags: zip, tar

My requirement is
using the 'zip' or 'tar' commands to generate the archive to standard output, and then streaming
that output back to server ( socket) where it can be fed to the standard input of another 'zip' or 'tar' command.

```
        String[] cmd = { "/bin/sh", "-c", "cd /Users//jon//Documents//t1/; zip -r - ." };
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
                cmd);
        
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = builder.start();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while (true) {
            line = r.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }
            out.write(line.getBytes());  -- > I want to write this output data over socket and server should consume it and write it to zip file.
            System.out.println(line);
        }
```

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? Both tools compress to stdout by default when not given filenames to operate on.

Comment: yes i read it. but now i want to transfer stdout to socket and on server side it should write it to zip file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=socat+socket